# Как нарисовать что либо на объекте QtCharts.QChartView?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qchartview

Пробую так, но выходит ошибка :

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCharts import *
import sys


class ChartViewMoi(QtCharts.QChartView):
    def __init__(self):
        super ().__init__ ()

    def paintEvent(self, event:QPaintEvent):
        qp = QPainter (self)
        pen = QPen (Qt.black, 2, Qt.SolidLine)
        qp.setPen (pen)
        qp.drawLine (0, 0, 700, 700)
        qp.end ()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow=QMainWindow()
chartView=ChartViewMoi()
mainWindow.setCentralWidget(chartView)
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ошибка :

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

Comment: Уберите qp.end()

Comment: Убрал , пропала только строка :

Comment: QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted

Comment: Думаю, что лучше рисовать на каком-нибудь QChart-наследнике, который добавлять о вью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
'''
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCharts import *
'''
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtChart import *    


def convert(word):
    return "".join(chr(e) for e in word.encode())


class ChartViewMoi(QChartView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ChartViewMoi, self).__init__(parent)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_OpaquePaintEvent)

        self.central_widget = QWidget()              
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)   
        button = QPushButton("Update")
        button.clicked.connect(self.draw_something)

        self.series = QLineSeries(name="random serie")
        for i in range(20):
            self.series << QPointF(0.1 * i, random.uniform(-10, 10))
        
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.setTitle("Title")
        self.chart.addSeries(self.series)
        self.chart.createDefaultAxes()
        axis_x, axis_y = self.chart.axes()
        axis_x.setLabelFormat(convert("%.2f分"))
        axis_y.setLabelFormat("%dmA")
        
        self.chartView = ChartViewMoi(self.chart)
       
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self.central_widget)    
        layout.addWidget(self.chartView)
        layout.addWidget(button)

    def draw_something(self):
        size = self.style().pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_SmallIconSize)
        size = 400
        pm = QPixmap(size, size)
        pm.fill(Qt.transparent)
        qp = QPainter(pm)
        pen = QPen(QColor(Qt.red), 4)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(0, size/2, size, size/2)
        
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(size, size)
        self.label.setPixmap(pm)
        self.label.show()
        
        qp.setFont(QFont('Times New Roman', 30))
        qp.drawText(100, 100, 'Hello PyQt5!')
        labe2 = QLabel(self)
        labe2.resize(size, size)
        labe2.setPixmap(pm)
        labe2.show()     

        pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2, Qt.SolidLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine (0, 0, 300, 300)        
        qp.end()                                         # !!!
        labe2 = QLabel(self)
        labe2.resize(size, size)
        labe2.setPixmap(pm)
        labe2.show()  
        
        self.update()                                    # !!!

        
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]